# Populating a table with JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, domo

I'm doing something very wrong and I can't for the life of me figure it out.  I'm a novice so that doesn't help.

```
    var res = httprequest.post('https://us3.api.samsara.com/v1/fleet/drivers?access_token=xxxxxxxx','{\"groupId\": 9999}');

DOMO.log('res: ' + res);

var toJson = JSON.parse(res); 


var header = lines[0].split(',');

datagrid.addColumn('id',datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);
datagrid.addColumn('name',datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);

for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
  console.warn( lines.[i].id );
  console.warn( lines.[i].name );
}
```

but the way the data is coming back is all screwey

```
res: {"drivers":[{"id":12345,"name":"Brian Smith"},
{"id":23456,"name":"Bruce Lee"},
{"id":89234,"name":"Carson Wentz"},
```

[image]

Comment: can you show the data you're working with (the res variable value)?

Comment: Why are you splitting the lines since you are working with an object? The cells more look like a ruined object to me. You should get the object keys in `lines[i]` and match the value to the column-header with the same key as a cell.

Comment: I think you need to do JSON.parse(res) first. then process the data

Comment: Why are you using string.split? If you have a string of JSON, parse it into a JavaScript array using JSON.parse(). Then it's trivial to loop over it and populate a table.

Comment: I'm a novice. I'm trying anything and everything to get data.  This code is the only thing I have been able to populate the table with.  No other reason than that for what I'm doing

Comment: did you google how to process JSON data using Javascript? Pretty sure you'd have found out about JSON.parse()

Comment: @ADyson what's google?  I actually really hoped someone would just do the script for me and didn't spend the past two days at work trying to figure it out myself.  Thanks I'll check this google thing you're talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[in progress - i'll get you a working sample just got pulled inot a meeting]
first parse it to json.

```
var res = '{"drivers":[{"id":12345,"name":"Brian Smith"},{"id":23456,"name":"Bruce Lee"},{"id":89234,"name":"Carson Wentz"}]}';

var toJson = JSON.parse(res); 

// you actually want to be iterating the drivers array

var lines = toJson['drivers'];

for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
  console.warn( lines[i].id );
  console.warn( lines[i].name );
}
```

Comment: Parsing JSON produces a object.

Comment: yes the "res" object in op's example contains a key called drivers and the value of "drivers" is an array containing objects with the keys id and name

Comment: I'm really sorry to ask this, but can you post it in the entire script?  I can't get it to work with how you have it posted here

Comment: it's calling on an api, so I'm parsing the data coming from an api.  Does that matter?  I just realized I didn't have the first part of my code.  I'm really sorry.  I appreciate all this assistance.

Comment: the api may already be returning json, most do, but some platforms send it back as text for an outdated security reasons, you likely don't need the json.parse and just need to understand working objects and arrays a bit better w3schools is a good place to go for a tutorial on that

Comment: @digital-pollution yes it is returning json

Comment: then: var lines = res['drivers'];

Comment: @Darkrum thank you, I understand your point.  This is how I learned SQL.  Lots of work and through the help of others in stack.

Comment: working with data and* dealing with requests is the first big step off the very basics, yeah you need to go find a tutorial but I always felt that stack should be a safe place to ask a question, even if the answer is go do a tutorial. You had a go first and posted your question within the guidelines so there's no need to be mean about it.    :)

Comment: You would still need to parse the returned JSON it doesn't automagicly become a object. Unless there's something in between doing it for you(i doubt it). You can easily figure it out by seeing if you can access properties on the response.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working.  Thank you everyone for your assistance.

```
var res = httprequest.post('https://us3.api.samsara.com/v1/
fleet/drivers?access_token=xxxxx','{\"groupId\": xxxxx}');

//DOMO.log('res: ' + res);

//added .drivers to read further into the JSON file before parsing
var data = JSON.parse(res).drivers;

datagrid.addColumn('id', datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);
datagrid.addColumn('name', datagrid.DATA_TYPE_STRING);

//lets you read data
DOMO.log('data: ' + data);

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var drivers = data[i].properties;
    datagrid.addCell(data[i].id);
    datagrid.addCell(data[i].name);
    datagrid.endRow();
}
```